# Probability of one number from infinite

Tags: probability

If we find probability of getting a number, say 800, from the set of infinite then the probability would be 1/infinite which is 0, but there are some possibilities to get 800. How!? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two mis-conceptions.  First, you're assuming that probability zero can't happen.  That's what we tell beginners, but actually, probability zero CAN happen.  E.g., let your height be $h$ inches, where $h$ is a real number.  There are infinite possibilities for $h$, but yet it settled on one.  The probability that you are the height that you are was zero, but it happened.

Second, you're assuming a uniform distribution, that is, you assume all numbers are equally likely to be chosen.  That's probably not the case.  If you ask a million people to chose a positive integer, a number like $800$ is apt to come up at least one.  But a number like $12,345,543,5432,323,234,762,345$ has a very small probability of being chosen.  So with a more realistic distribution function, you might have the probability of $800$ be non-zero.